# Android ArrayList file serialization

Tags: android, serialization, arraylist

I've read thousand of topics about android file serialization recently but I still didn't find working solution.

I have my serializable class, and activity where I serialize and deserialize `ArrayList` with serializable class elements in  `onResume()` and `onPause()` respectively.

My solution still throws IOException both in seriazlie and deserialize methods.

```
package classes;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;

public class Note implements Serializable {

    public Note() {
    }

    public Note(Date date, String name, GeoPoint geoPoint) {
        this.date = date;
        this.name = name;
        this.geoPoint = geoPoint;
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7789719052842264659L;

    private Date date;
    private String name;
    private GeoPoint geoPoint;

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public GeoPoint getGeoPoint() {
        return geoPoint;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Name: %S%nDate: %2$td-%2$tb-%2$tY%nTime: %2$tH:%2$tM:%2$tS", name, date);
    }
}
```

Here are my methods:

```
private void serializeQuotes() {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("test.txt", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(notes);
        oos.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Serialization error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void deserializeQuotes() {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("test.txt");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        notes = (ArrayList<Note>) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Deserialization error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    }
}
```

where `notes` are

```
ArrayList<Note>
```

I need to create file in AppFolder:

```
    File savedLocationsDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath().concat("/AppFolder"));
    if (!savedLocationsDirectory.exists()) savedLocationsDirectory.mkdirs();
    savedLocationsFile = new File(savedLocationsDirectory, "savedLocations.gc");
```

and I use then: `FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(savedLocationsFile);` and `FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(savedLocationsFile, true);`

In both cases serialization doesn't work.

Comment: *GeoPoint* is not *serializable*. Exception trace please.

Comment: Oh, it was so simple! Thanks.